# Drag and drop children of the same sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game using Sprite Kit and I want to be able to drag and drop boxes as they travel down the screen.

Here's the gist of the code: I spawn the boxes on a timer and they move down the screen.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBox"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func spawnBox() {
    /*        Set up the box        */

    addChild(box)

    let boxMoveDown = SKAction.moveToY(-100, duration: 5.0)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    box.runAction(SKAction.sequence([boxMoveDown, actionDone]))
}
```

But the problem is I how can I move a **specific** child which I am touching without affecting all the other 'children'? I understand that at the moment, every time I spawn a box it's exactly the same so I can't be specific when I set a individual child's position.

Here's what's inside my touchesBegan and touchesMoved functions

```
if let touch = touches.first {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)            
    let objects = nodesAtPoint(location) as [SKNode]

    if objects.contains(nodeAtPoint(location)) && nodeAtPoint(location).name == "box" {
        box.position = location
        box.removeAllActions()
        }
    }
```

The - `box.position = location` is what 
needs changing.

Hopefully you understand my idea. I've tried to keep included code to what's necessary. I'm quite new to Sprite Kit which you can probably tell.

Comment: When you detect that a node is selected, you'll need to remove the `SKAction` that makes the node move down the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you,  I would handle it this way:

Create a custom class for your box nodes that extends `SKSpriteNode`.

In this custom class,  override the touch property.

Then set the position inside this function based on location.

Now all you need to worry about is your `zPosition`, whatever child has the highest zPosition will be the one that gets called on touch.

You do not need to worry about `nodesAtPoint` or what not anymore,  the API will handle all that for you.

Comment: Exactly what k was thinking also.

Comment: How would I go about this?

Comment: Normally I do not mind giving code when it comes to complex problems, but in this case, I am not going to do that since I have explained the basic principles of what you need to do,  it is better for you to research and understand what is happening instead of just copying and pasting.  I have broken the answer into steps as it is,  so it should not be hard to go through my answer.